# Is it possible to use system variables in Oracle Form Libraries?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I need to switch off logic in library during Query mode.
I am using following condition:

```
IF :SYSTEM.MODE != 'ENTER-QUERY' THEN
```

When I add this condition in form everything works fine, but once I add this in library I receive compilation error:
[image]

Is there some kind of restriction that do not allow to use system variables in libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use them directly, but you can use name_in built-in to get the value:

```
if name_in(':SYSTEM.MODE') != 'ENTER-QUERY' THEN
```

The same applies to 'global' variables (you can't use global pseudo-block without built-ins like name_in or copy)

Answer (score 2):

Almost right, it's name_in('system.mode'), without the colon. Works the same with name_in('block.item') and name_in('global.global_name') etc